# How to plot 2 sets of categorical data from one data set on the same Box plot in R

Tags: javascript, r, multiple-columns, categorical-data, box

I have a spreadsheet of data with numerical values in one column and a second column named sex where it is either male or female.

How can I plot this data using a Boxplot so that I have separate plots for male and female but on the same graph?

Comment: Could you please explain what the notation means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As d.b mentioned,

```
boxplot(mpg ~ cyl, mtcars)
```

where the tilde means "is explained by". So in his example, the mpg of a car "is explained by" the number of cylinders. The graph shows a box for each of those number of cylinders.

Answer (score 1):

d.b's comment is referring to the command and arguments one needs in order to generate a boxplot of miles per gallon for cars of differing numbers of cylinders using a dataset that comes with base R called `mtcars`. The first argument `mpg ~ cyl` specifies the formula (create a boxplot of `mpg` with the grouping by `cyl`) and the second argument specifies the dataset (`mtcars`).

This should be enough to get you going where you subsitute your own formula for `mpg ~ cyl` and your own dataset for `mtcars`. Here's another example where I'm creating fake data with `rnorm` and `runif` (these functions randomly sample from a normal distribution and a uniform distribution respectively) and `trunc` truncates numbers (we want `runif` to give whole numbers):

```
df <- data.frame(vals = rnorm(n=100, mean=0, sd=1), sex = trunc(runif(n=100, min=0, max=2)))
boxplot(vals ~ sex, df)
```